# formatting datetime objects as strings for SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, momentjs

I am trying to unit test a new api endpoint I have built which queries a SQLite instance and returns the results.

I am seeding the SQLite instance from JSON, and this is the record I am trying to pick up:

```
{
    "model": "JobResponse",
    "data": {
        "id": 4,
        "JobId": "1",
        "createdAt": "2017-08-13 00:01"
    }
},
```

I usually use sequelize, and would use a momentjs object as a timeparam, but the query I need isn't possible in sequelize, so I am using a raw query. My js is generating the following query:

```
SELECT JobId, WHERE JobId = 2 AND createdAt > 2017-08-13 AND createdAt < 2017-08-14;
```

I am sure this is an issue with the formatting of the datetime element, but both the JSON seed and the SQL query have to be in string form, I have tried `moment().format()`, but then I get errors e.g:

> SQLITE_ERROR: near "00"

which is presumably because the moment format has spaces in it.

How should I be formatting these datetime parameters as strings?

## Update

As per the discussion in comments, I have now midified my query to contain inverted commas, e.g. `SELECT JobId, FROM JobResponses WHERE createdAt > '2017-08-10 00:00:01' AND createdAt < '2017-08-10 23:59:00' GROUP BY JobId;`

but I am still not getting any results returned

Comment: Did you try putting your datetime values inside `'`? `...AND  createdAt > '2017-08-13 00:01:00'`

Comment: @ZoharPeled OK, I now have this as a `SELECT JobId, FROM JobResponses WHERE createdAt > '2017-08-10 00:00:01' AND createdAt < '2017-08-10 23:59:00' GROUP BY JobId;` where the createdAt property in my seed is `"createdAt": "2017-08-10 07:11:35"`. The query retunrs 0 results

Comment: Well, at least you don't get a syntax error :-) I'm not an SQLite person, I work mainly with SQL Server, so I don't think I can answer this question.

Comment: The obvious question to ask is did you check what is in column `createdAt` and are there any values there that fulfill the `WHERE createdAt > '2017-08-10 00:00:01' AND createdAt < '2017-08-10 23:59:00'` criterion?

Comment: @varro well I posted the record above, so I think so?

Comment: I don't know anything the JSON syntax you've posted, but I *do* know that that you should *check* the actual contents of the database, preferably using the `sqlite3` command line tool, before *assuming* that you have suitable contents to satisfy your query.

Comment: I also notice that there are a couple of things that look suspicious about your JSON: (1) if `JobId` will be holding integers, your default should probably be `1` rather than `"1"`, and (2) the default value you gave for `createdAt` is an invalid date format - perhaps you intended `"2017-08-13 00:00:01"`?